# Displaying a list of records from a SQL table's column in WPF textbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to display list of all existing records from the database to the user when a textbox gets focus, and user types something. Basically replicating the function of the title bar in new question page in stack overflow website. Below is the code that I have written to test.

```
        Dim myadapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection
    Dim command As New SqlCommand
    Dim myDataSet As New DataSet

    connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=GAMING;Initial Catalog=BasicDB;User ID=sa;Password=J1tendr@")
    connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand()
    command.Connection = connection
    command.CommandText = "select EnteredValue from BasicTable"

    myadapter.SelectCommand = command

    myadapter.Fill(myDataSet)



    If myadapter IsNot Nothing Then

        SurveyNo.DataContext = myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
    End If
```

This code gives me the first record when I focus on the textbox with the following binding:

```
Text="{Binding [EnteredValue],Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I don't want to display just one field, but a list of all possible values. I think I am missing something in binding property.

Comment: Is the text box rigged up to display multi-lines as opposed to just one?

Comment: No. It is just normal text box.

Comment: In that case might you not be better off with a list box?  Sorry I can't be more specific as to your problem, wpf is still a learning curve for me.

Comment: I was thinking of listbox or rather combo box as well. But I soon found it was way too difficult to manage validations in combo box. Plus, I am not sure if combo box will allow me to type "Com" and display "Add Comment" for example.